# Net::SSH perl script for windows 7

Tags: perl

I am using windows 64 bit active perl 5.20 sw to login a linux/unix server.
From the same windows machine i can do ssh with my user id & password without any problem. But when i am using the following script i am getting
Permission denied

## (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic, public key, password,keyboard-interactive).

Any idea how to troubleshoot it?
Thanks

```
  #!/Perl64/bin/

   use strict;
   use Net::SSH qw(sshopen2);
   use strict;

   my $host = '10.120.xx.xx';
   my $user = 'user';
   my $pass = 'password';
   my $cmd = '/bin/sh';
   my @commands = ('df -k','free','uptime');

   sshopen2("$user\@$host", *READER, *WRITER, "$cmd") || die "ssh: $!";

   while (<READER>) {
      chomp();
      print "$_\n";
   }

   close(READER);
   close(WRITER);
```

Comment: Where do you provide the password to the remote host?

Answer (score 0):

sshopen2 does not support password. It is explain in the perldoc page : http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH/SSH.pm
(see FAQ)

The recommendation are either to set up rsa key or to use the module expect (that mimic user input)